# ASP.NET MVC Media With Fallback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, html5-video

I am integrating videos into a website we have which I have never done before, I have been searching all afternoon as I am looking for a robust solution in which first HTML5 is tried and if not supported then falls back to flash or silverlight and if neither are supported just displays a link to download the video or something along those lines.  Does anyone know of a good example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems perfect:

http://mediaelementjs.com/